# Why is set -e not scoped by a parenthesis in a Bash script?

Tags: bash

Given the following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

(
  set -x -e
  false
  echo e1 $?
) || {
  echo e2 $?
  exit 1
}
```

which gives this output:

```
+ false
+ echo e1 1
e1 1
```

Explain why we never see any output for the line containing "e2"?

Compare that script with:

```
#!/bin/bash

(
  set -x -e
  false
  echo e1 $?
  true
)

echo e2 $?
```

Which gives this output:

```
$ bash /tmp/foo.sh
+ false
e2 1
$
```

Which is the output I do expect.

So in both cases the `set -x -e` is properly scoped, but then in the first script, the `||` operator is seemingly ignored?

Bash version:

```
$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$
```

Comment: ? Where do you see that set is not scoped? `why we never see any output for the line containing "e2"?` There is literally `e2 1` output in the result you posted.

Comment: It is scoped? You only see the effects of `set -e -x` in the subshell used by the statements in the parens. What were you expecting?

Comment: You don't see trace output for the `echo e2 $?` command because `set -x` is *also* restricted to the subshell. Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to see what's happening.

Comment: Rats. I forgot to include the original script that did not show that `set -x -e` was properly scoped. I should have reviewed it more carefully. I'll update the question.

Comment: Now I've added both versions of the script.  It is as if Bash is ignoring the `||` operator even though it sees the `false` and exits out of that `(...)` subshell as I would have expected.

Comment: `he || operator is seemingly ignored?` You see in the output `echo e1 1`. `echo` exits with 0 exit status. So `||` operator is not ignored, becuase the right side is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why we never see any output for the line containing "e2"?

Because `set -e` does not work when it is part of a `||` chain, the first `( )` subshell exits with the exit status of the last command executed, which is `echo`, which exits with a zero exit status. Because of `||` the right side is not executed, so `echo e2` is not executed so there is no `e2` in output.

From bash manual https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html :

> -e
>
> Exit immediately if [...]. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is [...] part of any command executed in a && or || list [..]

You may be interested in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 .